# I can't hide Floating Action Button?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I am trying to hide my FAB in a button click, but it's not working.?

My XML

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabbb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp"
    android:tint="@color/md_white_1000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/show"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:text="HIDE" />
```

My Activity

```
show.setOnClickListener {
        fabbb.visibility == View.GONE
    }
```

Comment: Use `fabbb.visibility = View.GONE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the method [`hide`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton.html#hide()):

```
fab.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is doing nothing, instead of returning `true` or `false` (most probably `true`, as you are using `comparison` instead of `equal-to`).

You should write code as

```
show.setOnClickListener {
    fabbb.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Or even you can use `fabbb.hide()`, as another answer suggested if you need animation too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call a function to hide and show FAB

to hide `fab.hide()`
to show `fab.show()`
Check the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#hide_1)